# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress configmap 301 redirect

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Using an NGINX Ingresss in Kubernetes, I can't see a way to forward my traffic from non-www to www, or to another domain etc on a per-host basis

I've tried looking in configmap docs but can't see what I need. Maybe it can go in the ingress itself?

I've also seen an example using annotations but this seems to be ingress-wide, so I couldn't have specific redirects per host

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indeed a redirect is possible with a simple annotation:

- [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://www.gothereinstead.com`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#permanent-redirect)
- [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#redirect-fromto-www)

But as you mentioned, it's "Ingress" wide and not configurable per host, per domain or even per path. So you'll have to do it yourself through the [`ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation, which gives you a great deal of power thanks to regular expressions:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: self-made-redirect
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($host = 'blog.yourdomain.com') {
        return 301 https://yournewblogurl.com;
      }
      if ($host ~ ^(.+)\.yourdomain\.com$) {
        return 301 https://$1.anotherdomain.com$request_uri;
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ...
```

If you are not quite used to NGINX, you'll know more about what's possible in the snippet, particularly what is the `$host` variable right in [the NGINX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables).

Comment: I've just deployed this and it works perfectly thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it was different before but now it was pretty hard to find a working solution. This answer is the one the helped the most but some things need to be changed: it is not ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet, it's nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet

Answer (score 5):

To redirect all traffic regardless of using HTTP or HTTPS from example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to newdomain.example.com I ended up with the following solution.

In this example I'm also using cert-manager.io to request the certs for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com.

The redirect is done using the annotation [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#permanent-redirect)

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: redirect-example-to-newdomain
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://newdomain.example.com
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.com
      - www.example.com
      secretName: example.com-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
    - host: www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with annotations server-snippet. When the certificate is renewed, the process crashes. When I remove annotations, renewed certificate is successful. Is there another solution? For example, creating a redirect 301 in separate pod?

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
        certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
        ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
        meta.helm.sh/release-name: DOMAIN
        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: DOMAIN
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          location ~ ^/online-web {
            return 301 /online;
          }
          if ($host = 'DOMAIN-alias.cz') {
            return 301 https://DOMAIN.cz;
          }
          if ($host ~ ^(.+)\.DOMAIN-alias\.cz$) {
            return 301 https://$1.DOMAIN.cz$request_uri;
          }
          if ($host = 'DOMAIN-alias-2.cz') {
            return 301 https://DOMAIN.cz;
          }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 128k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      if ($host ~ "csas.woltair.cz") {
          return 301 https://woltair.cz/zakaznik/doporuceni;
      }
............
............
  - host: csas.woltair.cz
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: woltair-cz-fe
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /zakaznik/doporuceni
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31025826)